# Store Wordpress "uploads" folder on another server

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ftp, cdn

I have four servers and and on one of these servers i have installed Wordpress for selling digital files. For security reasons i don't want to keep files on the same server as Wordpress is installed. I want to move "Uploads" folder to other three servers and connect theme to Wordpress core. So whenever i upload something via Wordpress i want it to be transferred to the second or third server based on file format. How is such thing possible?

P.S: Unfortunately i can't use Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74180/upload-images-to-remote-server/78129#78129

It is a bit outdated, but the code says is still does the trick. However, to do exactly what you need, some modifications are required.

Hopefully this will be helpful to you. Have a nice day!